# adding same item with unique index to state array on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am working on a problem where an state array items is blank and needs to be added with an object item on click of a button

> newItem={index:0,val:"a"};
> items=[newItem1,newItem2];
> so expected outcome is items:[{index:0,val:"a"},{index:1,val:"a"}]

I wrote code:

```
state:{
    items:[],
    counter:0,
}
const newItem={index:0,val:"a"};

onclick=()=>
{
    newItem.index=this.state.counter;
    
    this.setState(prevState => ({items:[...prevState.items,newItem]}),()=>{console.log(this.state.rowData);});
    this.setState({counter:this.state.counter+1});
}
```

However it is returning me

**items:[{index:1,val:"a"},{index:1,val:"a"}] and on each click** index of all array items get updated.
I tried concat, push, all are updating index for both array elements.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here. You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is not so clear...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by always picking the last index property of the last element. Example:

```js
const arr = [{index: 1, val: "a"}];
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  arr.push({index: arr[arr.length - 1].index + 1, val: "a"});
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<button>increment + </button>
```